# Views filter by type and taxonomy

Tags: database, views

I have two types of content every one with two taxonomies:

TYPE A with Taxonomy 1 (multiple)

TYPE B with Taxonomy 2 (multiple)

Now I created a view with 3 filters exposed:

Node type: A or B or both

Taxonomy 1

Taxonomy 2

Now if I choose, all the nodes A and B with the term x (taxonomy 1) and the term y (taxonomy 2) does not return nothing.

I tried to change the AND and OR, but nothing comes out from the query.

Do you think it is possible a query like this with views filters?

Comment: Hi carlo, please remove solved from your question. If you found a solution add it as an own answer (but expand the link, providing content here, keeping it as reference). To indicate your issue is solved you can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

Yes it's possible with group filters, but I discovered that there is a bug when grouped value contains an array (multiple items).

A patch fixed the problem: http://drupal.org/node/2224601#comment-8627337

Answer (score 0):

Use group filters

First views filters group

```
Type A AND taxonomy 1
```

Condition between groups

```
OR
```

Second views filters group

```
Type B AND taxonomy 2
```

Comment: hi, I tried but with exposed filters (or not exposed) seems not to work.